# how to send cookies for userA for userB's session in webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, session-cookies, digital-signature, webapp2

Webapp2 session's secure cookie is signed by the server's private key. This keeps someone from crafting their own cookies and having the server accept them. However, couldn't someone take the cookies from session X and pass them as cookies in another session Z (man in the middle attack)? It seems that the only way to prevent this is to require that one of the cookies be used to identify the user for which the cookies apply to. This way, only cookies meant for a session w/ user X can only be used for a session w/ user X; they cannot be used w/ a session for user Z.

Example where the server doesn't validate a 'user id' cookie (insecure):

1. server sets cookie C for user X
2. server sets cookie D for user Y
3. user Y sends cookie D while impersonating X
4. since both C and D are signed w/ the server's private key, the server accepts D and treats it as if it is a valid cookie in X's account

Example where the server validates a 'user id' cookie (secure):

1. server sets cookie C for user X, and also sets an 'id' cookie w/ the id of user X
2. server sets cookie D for user Y, and also sets an 'id' cookie w/ the id of user Y
3. user Y sends cookie D while impersonating X
4. the server will look at the 'id' cookie that accompanies D and see that the id is for     user Y. The server then realizes that the supplied cookie can only apply to Y, and thus won't treat it as valid for user X

Please confirm whether or not a 'user id' cookie needs to be checked in order to preclude someone from taking the cookies from session X and pass them as cookies in another session Z.